# What is the convention around appositional phrases and commas in formal mathematical writing?

Tags: soft-question, article-writing

Does anyone have any useful guidelines for comma usage around appositional phrases in article writing? For instance which are preferred among the following pairs?

1. A group $G$ is nilpotent if...
2. A group, $G$, is nilpotent if...

---

3. The Klein-4 group $K_4$ is...
4. The Klein-4 group, $K_4$, is...

I believe that 1 and 3 are preferred, but in the second example this conflicts with the way we use commas when not writing mathematics, e.g., "The first man on the moon, Neil Armstrong,..." we use commas because the first phrase uniquely identifies Neil Armstrong, and so adding his name is not essential to the meaning of the sentence.

I'm particularly worried about the following thing I've written:

"The jump, $Y'$, of $Y$..."

Here I think the commas are needed (as I'm interrupting a phrase). I wrote it this way because I didn't want to write "The jump of $Y$ $Y'$" which looks like nonsense.

Comment: I do use cases 1 and 3. I think one can treat this like the Oxford comma: use it if you want.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I think you and I have very different friends. Mine get very angry about the Oxford comma.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I don't think this is like the Oxford comma at all, other than the fact that commas are involved in both.

Comment: I agree 1 and 3 are preferred by most writers, despite your valid point about 4 vs. 3.

Comment: @James I'm of the camp of "Use the dang Oxford comma." It makes the writing a bit more clear.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I really don't have much of an opinion on the matter, I just do like to point out that it is certainly not the case that the oxford comma never increases ambiguity; To wit: We invited the stripper, JFK, and Stalin.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Certainly, because "The Astronaut" does not uniquely identify anything. The cases I am worried about is where I am introducing notation for an object or a function which (in my subject) has a unique identifying name, i.e., situations analogous to my second example.

Comment: I deleted my answer because on further consideration it seems to me I merely restated points that were already made. If I can improve the answer I may restore it (if I still can).

Answer (score 1):

You are right, models `1.` and `3.` are preferred in mathematics; in your last example, I would avoid the comma too (adding a "that is" or "i.e.").
In general, follow this rule: "make it simple" when writing mathematics or computer science texts.

Comment: Just for clarity. You would prefer "The jump $Y'$ of $Y$..."

Comment: Yes, I just edited.